# Strange fcitx-mozc behavior with ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, input-method, fcitx

I use ArchLinux and I have problems with Japanese IME.

When I write by Japanese IME, a character can't be in text area with Skype, Android Studio, etc. (maybe those aren't gtk and qt apps)

[image]

It works for Chromium, gnome-terminal, though.

Do you have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

fcitx(-anthy, but that should not matter) works fine with Skype here.

My guess is that you're missing some environment variables.

```
$ set | grep -i fcitx
GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
```

Comment: Thanks, @frostschutz. I confirmed that settings.



```sh
$ set | grep -i -a fcitx
GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
XMODIFIERS='@im=fcitx'
```
I suppose that It looks good. What do you think about this?